# Need to solve yarn install error: fatal error: 'napi.h' file not found

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, node-modules, yarnpkg

I upgraded node version 12 to 14.20.0, and Angular CLI 9 to 14.0.7
I use MacOS Monterey 12.5, M1 chip

When I run the command `yarn clean:npm && yarn install`, I got this error.
I tried `yarn add` command for not found node-modules, and nothing changed.

`$yarn install`

**Error**

```
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/myName/projects/popopo/projectName/frontend/node_modules/nice-napi: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp-build
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/myName/projects/popopo/projectName/frontend/node_modules/nice-napi
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@8.1.0
gyp info using node@14.20.0 | darwin | arm64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.4 found at \"/Users/myName/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/versions/3.10.4/bin/python3\"
gyp info spawn /Users/myName/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/versions/3.10.4/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/myName/projects/popopo/projectName/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/myName/projects/popopo/projectName/frontend/node_modules/nice-napi/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/myName/projects/popopo/projectName/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/myName/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.20.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/myName/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.20.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/myName/projects/popopo/projectName/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/myName/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.20.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/myName/projects/popopo/projectName/frontend/node_modules/nice-napi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/nothing.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/nothing.a
warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: archive library: Release/nothing.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nice_napi/binding.o
/bin/sh: pathos/projectName/frontend/node_modules/node-addon-api: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/obj.target/nice_napi/binding.o] Error 127
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/myName/projects/popopo/projectName/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:285:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
gyp ERR! command \"/Users/myName/.anyenv/envs/nodenv/versions/14.20.0/bin/node\" \"/Users/myName/projects/popopo/projectName/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp\" \"rebuild\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/myName/projects/popopo/projectName/frontend/node_modules/nice-napi
gyp ERR! node -v v14.20.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
../binding.cc:1:10: fatal error: 'napi.h' file not found
✨  Done in 127.04s.
```

Comment: Try this https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/main/macOS_Catalina.md